# Excel VBA Code - How to call certain actions to files created

Tags: excel, macros, activex

I am writing a piece of code in Excel VBA in which I needed to create a macro which allows the user to click the ActiveX button as a result of which the file is then saved to a specified location. Once this new file is created, I wanted to code so the new file (which successfully saves in the alternate specified location) does not have the ActiveX Command Button is not present. Also, once the button is clicked from the original file, I wanted to somehow make the master file close and the newly saved file to automatically open. Please can someone help?

Code so far:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Dim SaveName As String
    SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Text
    With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs "File path Specified" & _
    SaveName & ".xls"
    .Close 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first solution (depending on what you really need to do) is the following:

Firstly you will need this:

```
Me.SaveCopyAs "<full_Path>"
```

See more on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx

This will create a copy of the file to the specified path with whatever name you want. Before you do that, you could hide your button and then use save as copy to save it with the button hidden.

Finally if you want to close the original and open the copy then you have to give to the copy a different name. Then open the new file and close the original.

Your code should look similar to this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Dim SaveName As String
    SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Text
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Worksheets("<your_worksheet>").CommandButton1.visible = False
        .SaveCopyAs "File path Specified" & SaveName & ".xls"
    End With
    Workbooks.Open ("File path Specified" & SaveName & ".xls")
    Workbooks("<Original_name.xlsm>").close False
End Sub
```

Another Solution could be saving the workbook with SaveAs. Before that save the orginal. Hide the button. And saveas will close the original and open the new one automatically.

Your code should look something like that:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Dim SaveName As String
    SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Text
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Save
        .Worksheets("<your_worksheet>").CommandButton1.visible = False
        .SaveAs "File path Specified" & SaveName & ".xls"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Blenikos. Thanks for your answer. When i use this, the line with .CommandButton1.Visible=False returns an error saying object doesn't support this property or method?

Comment: I haven't tested the code so propably there are some mistakes. I would need your excel file to test it. However, I have edited my current answer and now it should work. Please let me know if it does!

Comment: Hi Blenikos, on the aprt where we have .Worksheets("<your_worksheet>") do i need to write my file location and file name? Or just the sheet name?

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. You are a life saver indeed!

Comment: @Syed Glad it worked! As I understand it you are new at SO so welcome to our community. Please do the tour on how the site works and if the above answer helped please accept it (huge tick mark on the left of the answer) to help future users to find the answer easier